# SQL Interbase 2009 execute statement inside a for execute statement: unexplained behaviour

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, nested, interbase

I am facing the following problem with Interbase 2009:

Inside a procedure I've nested a EXECUTE STATEMENT inside FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT. The outer EXECUTE STATEMENT collects some data and puts them into some local variables. Depending on the values that the outer EXECUTE STATMENT returns I am building a second SQL String. I'm building both Statements inside the procedure.

Pseudocode:

```
SQLSTRING = 'SELECT TEST FROM TABLENAME';
FOR EXECUTE STATMENT SQLSTRING INTO :MYVAR
DO
BEGIN
  SQLUPDATESTRING = 'UPDATE TABLENAME SET ' || ' TEST2 = "' || MYVAR || '";';      
  EXECUTE STATEMENT SQLUPDATESTRING;
  /* PLACEHOLDER */
END
```

This code leads to the error:

```
Invalid token.
Could not execute statement : .
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
```

If I add an "CONTINUE", "EXIT" or "SUSPEND" to the /*PLACEHOLDER*/ it works for the first row. The statements that I want to be executed inside the loop are also correct ( tested it with debug returns ).

So my question is why does Interbase think that the statement is empty ( i think that it think it is empty because it tells me: "Could not execute statement : ." ).

If I abort the loop directly I can see that my variables are not empty, especially the one that holds the SQL String to be executed.

I tried execute only one statement inside of one procedure. So I moved the second execution into a second procedure, but this didn't solve the problem.

Has any one an idea? I'm trying to solve this for some time now...

Comment: I solved it. The problem occured because i used double quotation marks instead of single quotation marks.